# Which parser can read the Spring and Hibernate XML files?

Tags: spring, hibernate

To read XML file data we need a parser so which parser is used internally to read spring, hibernate XML files

Comment: Some XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you only need the XmlSchemas, they are to be found at the begining of the typical XML-Files (filetype .xsd). Using these the parser can be generated using JAXB